# What web servers can I install on the Raspberry Pi?

Tags: web-server

I'm considering using a bunch of Raspberry Pi's as low-cost distributed load balanced web servers. This is probably a terrible idea but I wanted to investigate it anyway.

Could I install IIS or something similar on a Raspberry Pi?

Comment: Not IIS (There is a LInux port but it sucks.. duh!?) Using nginx is the best (in my opinion, for Linux based systems) way of doing laod balancing. nginx was designed for embedded systems but is used on large datacentres. It if very efficient, fast and versatile (but maybe a tinsy bit more complicated to setup.. but not thaaaat bad!) You can run .NET using MONO, its OK. Running ASP or MVC also sucks on Linux Mono. IIS and .NET should only run on x86 machines on Windows.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As ppumkin pointed out the in comments, don't use IIS. You [**can definitely use nginx**](http://www.ducky-pond.com/posts/2013/Sep/setup-a-web-server-on-rpi/). [**Apache also works**](http://www.wikihow.com/Make-a-Raspberry-Pi-Web-Server).

Finally, don't discount the possibility of a simple node.js script to implement a server. Depending on what you want to do (dynamic content versus static), you may get even better performance than with nginx.

Comment: as you decide yourself for a debian based distro https://wiki.debian.org/WebServers ..

Answer (score 0):

lighttpd is a nice lightweight server, designed to use as little memory as possible (http://www.lighttpd.net/)

Answer (score 0):

Apache is what I use on my RPi. The raspberry pi isn't very well suited for use as a web server, but it is well worth a go.

Comment: -1 Apache works just fine as a web server. That is its sole reason for existing.

Comment: @Jacobm001 I meant the raspberry pi

Comment: Still, a lot of people use the RPi as a web server. Should work just fine for most applications.

Comment: @Jacobm001 It works great, just is a bit slow